# Designing a ListView like Samsung's contacts view

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to design side index for `ListView`. I am able to achieve this by dynamically adding   `TextViews`(alphabets) to a vertical `LinearLayout`. This is working fine for fixed size screens, but for some small height screens all 26 `TextViews` are not coming.

Comment: I guess you need to calculate the per view height you need and scale the TextViews accordingly